# What am I getting this puppet 6 error after upgrade?

Tags: centos, puppet

I've upgraded my puppetserver to puppet 6, along with the puppetDB and Puppet agent on a node, when running `puppet agent -t` I get this error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on
>   SERVER: Internal Server Error: org.jruby.exceptions.SecurityError:
>   (SecurityError) Illegal method definition of method 'normalized?' on
>   line 4' in legacy function.

I've checked the CAs for the nodes and they are all there and all modules are upto date

Comment: The error message seems to be implicating a problem with a plugin function in one of your modules.  It does not look like a problem with Puppet itself.